# Find the `{}` part which doesn't have outer `{}` by regex

Tags: java, regex

The title is not clear, so I write some sample to explain.

There is a string, which contains many nested `{}`s:

```
 /users/{<\w{2,4}\d{3}>id}
```

You can see I use `{}` as a placeholder for path variables, and it can have regex inside and which can also have `{}`.

How to write a regex with java to parse the path pattern, find the `{}` parts which don't have outer `{}`. For this example, it should be `{<\w{2,4}\d{3}>id}`.

Thanks~

**UPDATE**

The given example is too simple, it can be:

```
/users/{<\w{2,4}\d{3}>id}/{action}/{<\w{2,4}\d{3}>targetId}
```

The result should be:

```
{<\w{2,4}\d{3}>id}
{action}
{<\w{2,4}\d{3}>targetId}
```

So `\\{.*\\}` doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need to use regex for this? It's getting very close to the realm of parsers, and hand crafting a simple matcher for the {} should  be a lot easier, if the regex engine you use can even handle the amount of backreferences you will need.

Comment: This question appears to be an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets

Comment: @aix, thanks, that's the exactly the same question I'm looking for.

Comment: What's the expected output in the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you have such case as `/users/{regex1}/{regex2}` ?

If yes, in this case `"\\{.*\\}"` will return `"{regex1}/{regex2}"`. :(

If not `"\\{(.*)\\}"` is good enough, being greedy you'll go for the whole expression you asked for. ;)

EDIT:

With your edited question then the comment from @aix above was the right answer : 
[Find the `{}` part which doesn't have outer `{}` by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317660/find-the-part-which-doesnt-have-outer-by-regex/10317768#comment13281949_10317660)

He pointed out your problem is similar with the one solved there: [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

Comment: The first is solved by a lazy regex and the second by greedy regex. As `Dervall` pointed out a hand-written parser will do the job right. Regex is ill-suited here.

Comment: lazy regex will fail according to given use case `/users/{<\w{2,4}\d{3}>id}`. `"\\{.*?\\}"` would return `{<\w{2,4}` chain. Anyway I agree that for general purpose regex is not good here, otherwise than real simple situation.

Comment: See my updated question. The given sample is too simple, so I add complex one :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misinterpreting your example.  But, your second example is:

```
/users/{<\w{2,4}\d{3}>id}/{action}/{<\w{2,4}\d{3}>targetId}
```

The result should be:

```
{<\w{2,4}\d{3}>id}
{action}
{<\w{2,4}\d{3}>targetId}
```

Are your `{}`'s that you want always going to be inside a delimiting `/`?  If, so, then you could do this easy enough by splitting on `/` and then just checking each result:

```
String test = "/users/{<\\w{2,4}\\d{3}>id}/{action}/{<\\w{2,4}\\d{3}>targetId}";
String[] pieces = test.split("(?<!\\\\)/");
for (String piece : pieces) {
    if (piece.matches("^\\{.*")) {
        /* do whatever */
    }
}
```

Where I've put in a complicated split assuming that an escaped `/` isn't a delimiter.

Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?